# Total charge on capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Hello I have this circuit, I want determine the maximum charge on the capacitor c, but I can't understand how to calculate it?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered giving it a try?

Comment: Ask yourself what the maximum voltage will be on the capacitor. Can you solve that?

Comment: I'm not sure why you've accepted 135838's answer, because it's wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only sign of progress is the OP accepting an answer that is plainly wrong

Comment: *Hint:*  When C is finished charging the current through R3 is ??? therefore the  voltage across R3 will be ??? . The voltage across R2 will be ??? and so the voltage across C will be ??? So if know C, and you know V you can calculate Q from Q=CV.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

After switch **S** closing, the capacitor **C** will start to charge. After some time it will eventually charge up to **V** volts. So the maximum charge is V.

Comment: Voltage is voltage and measured in Volts, charge is another thing and it is measured in Coulombs.

Comment: Have another go. There's little point in providing an answer that's incorrect. Ask yourself how much current is flowing in each resistor once the capacitor is charged.